# Wordpress - posting content without blockquote or images

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Trying to post the content of a post WITHOUT the blockquote or images. My code takes out the images but still puts in the block quote and text.

```
<?php
    $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
    $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
    $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
        echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple error here - your second call to `preg_replace()` is using `get_the_content()`, which is the unmodified content - so you're basically doing away with what you did on your first line.

For the second line to use the output of the first line, your second parameter needs to be `$content`:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', $content);
```